# adding date on xaxis and value on Yaxis in MP android Line chart?

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I am using Library MPAndroid,`compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'`

I have to pass dates in x-axis and value on y-axis in MPAndroid Line chart, when I am passing values in x-axis or yaxis, the app gets crashed showing `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` `Exception`, with array size as -2.

How, can I acheive this? I have used xAxis value formatter as well. Please, help.Below is my code

`{ 
  mChart.setOnChartGestureListener(this);
        mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);`

```
    mChart.setNoDataTextDescription("You need to provide data for the chart.");
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    mChart.setDragEnabled(false);
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);

    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(270);
    xAxis.setAxisLineWidth(3);
    xAxis.setAxisMaxValue(310f);
    xAxis.setTextSize(13f);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines();
    leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(330f);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(50f);
    leftAxis.setAxisLineWidth(3);
    leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    leftAxis.setTextSize(13f);
    leftAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    leftAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);
    leftAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);

    mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.animateX(2500, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuart);

    mChart.invalidate();

}

      private ArrayList<String> setXAxisValues() {
    return typesList;
}

private ArrayList<Entry> setYAxisValues() {
    float[] EndTime = new float [glucoseReportReading.length];
    for (int i=0; i<glucoseReportReading.length;i++)
    {
        float number = Float.parseFloat(glucoseReportReading[i]);
        float rounded = (int) Math.round(number * 1000) / 1000f;
        EndTime[i] = rounded;
    }

    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for(int i=0;i<glucoseReadingArrayList.size();i++){
        yVals.add(new Entry(EndTime[i],i));
    }

    return yVals;
}

private void setData() {
    GraphModelClass graphModelClass = new GraphModelClass();
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = setYAxisValues();
    ArrayList<String> xVals1 = setXAxisValues();
    graphModelClass.setyVals(yVals1);
    graphModelClass.setxVals(xVals1);

    ArrayList<String> xVals = graphModelClass.getxVals();//setXAxisValues();
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = graphModelClass.getyVals();//setYAxisValues();

    LineDataSet set1;

    set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "DataSet 1");
    set1.setFillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    set1.setColor(Color.RED);
    set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLUE);
    set1.setLineWidth(2f);
    set1.setCircleRadius(4f);
    set1.setDrawCircleHole(true);
    set1.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set1.setDrawFilled(true);
   /* ArrayList<LineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<LineDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1);*/
    LineData data = new LineData(xVals,set1);
    mChart.setData(data);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an `AxisValueFormatter` is correct. The Problem you are facing is that the Library wants to draw labels before and after your chart, but can't find values in your array.

You can solve this by checking the indizes and retourning empty labels.

```
@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    if (value < 0 || value > glucoseReportTime.size() - 1)
        return "";
    return glucoseReportTime[(int) value];
}
```

If you don't want empty spaces before and after your chart you can further use

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(<yourMinum>);
xAxis.setAxisMaximum(<yourMaximum>);
```

Comment: app is getting crashed showing   java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -2
                                                                                      at com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer.generateTransformedValuesLine(Transformer.java:181

Comment: i guess your x-values are not sorted. Unfortunately the lib can't handle unsorted entries. If that is the case try to sort it before.

Comment: see what i want is to display date on x-axis and value on y axis. Now, could you please tell me how to pass these values in MP android Line chart. I have changed the library version from 3.0.0 to 2.3.3.

Comment: It is ok how you did it. not sure what the problem is actually. can you show us the whole code regarding your mChart or the values? Changing back to a lower version is not something i would recommend.

Comment: I have updated my code. Actually, the previous library which I was using was a beta version.That`s why I thought changing it back to a lower version.

Comment: btw why are you using 2 different dataSets but setting only one? For one line you only need one LineDataSet with 1 ArrayList with entries. Each entry has x and y coordinates. And apparently you removed your ValueFormatter...

Comment: oh sry - i was wrong, you are using everything but the existance of xVals and yVals looks strange to me. Normally you have 1 list of entries and create a `LineDataSet` out of it. Afterwards you create a `LineData` ojbect with this lineDataSet and set this LineData for the chart like in this example. Take a look into this example https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Getting-Started.
I would suggest you just use one dataSet and a ValueFormatter which i explained in the Answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line :

```
for(int i=0;i<glucoseReadingArrayList.size();i++)
```

with:

```
for(int i=0;i<typesList.size();i++)
```